# Differential equation $t^2y''+2ty'-2y=6t^{-2}+3t?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this differential equation?

$$t^2y''+2ty'-2y=6t^{-2}+3t?$$

Thanks :)

Which method, exist any quickly method?

Comment: Do you care for the method or for the result ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to solve the associated homogeneous ODE first and then solve the non-homogeneous ODE by (for example) [variation of parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters). Every ODE like: $$ax^2y''+bxy'+cy=0$$ is called a [Cauchy-Euler equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation). Follow the [method](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EulerEquations.aspx).

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Thanks brother. :-) $+^+$ for you. :)

Comment: $\ddot\smile +1$

Comment: @amWhy: It is nice to see the shining Sun here. :-)

Comment: Hi, my dear Babak! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe notice that in the left hand side, the terms are in the same degree, for the coefficient (for example $t^2$) and for the derivative ( y'').

So try to look for some solutions of the form $t^\alpha$ (for the homogeneous equation)

The left hand side becomes : $(\alpha (\alpha -1) + 2 \alpha -2). t^\alpha$

So the homogeneous solutions are $t^\alpha$ and $t^\beta$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $X(X-1)+2X -2$, id est $1$ and $-2$.